# What should i do to replace this old manifest v2 code for manifest v3 for Google Chrome Extenion

Tags: javascript, css, json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

So I am making an extension and I am using a template from an old youtube video that uses manifest v2 and I am using manifest v3 but how do I exchange this code

```
"background": {
    "service_worker":
        "popup.js",
        "persistent": true
},
```

The error I get from chrome is this

```
Failed to load extension
File: ~/Chrome extenions /BackgroundChanger
Error: The "background.persistent" key cannot be used with manifest_version 3. Use the "background.service_worker" key instead.
Could not load manifest.
```

I expected manifest v2 and v3 should be at least similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration guide can be found here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/.

The error you get specifically is caused by having a `scripts` property in the `background` object. It should be replaced with `"service_worker": "popup.js"`.

Comment: Thanks that worked but now i am getting this error

`Failed to load extension
File
~/Chrome extenions /BackgroundChanger
Error
The "background.persistent" key cannot be used with manifest_version 3. Use the "background.service_worker" key instead.
Could not load manifest.`

Comment: Just remove `persistent` property - it is not necessary as for V3 it terminates when not in use.